# Angular 2 How can I inject a custom provider into a service?

Tags: typescript, angular

Using typescript, In main.ts I have:

```
let myProvider = provide("message", { useValue: 'Hello' });

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  myProvider
]);
```

How can I inject this into my service (which is in a different file)? (Keep in mind I'm not using the @Component annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the `@Inject` decorator:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(@Inject('message') message:string) {
  }
}
```

Don't forget to configure the service provider. For example when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SomeService, myProvider ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the [Dependency Injection doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) no longer mentions string tokens, I recommend using an [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OpaqueToken-class.html):

app/config.ts

```
import {OpaqueToken, provide} from 'angular2/core';

export let MY_MESSAGE = new OpaqueToken('my-msg');
export let myProvider = provide(MY_MESSAGE, { useValue: 'Hello' });
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {myProvider} from './config';
import {MyService} from './MyService';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [myProvider, MyService],
  template: `{{msg}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _myService:MyService) { 
    this.msg = this._myService.msg;
  }
}
```

app/MyService.ts

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {MY_MESSAGE} from './config';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_MESSAGE) private _message:String) { 
    this.msg = _message;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C1k3aKxGEveNTPbyXHSK?p=preview)</kbd>